# Citations not showing up in text and bibliography

Tags: bibliographies

I have a `References.bib` file that contains all references I will cite. My `Paper.tex` looks like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makeidx}  % allows for indexgeneration
\usepackage{ifpdf}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{graphicx} 

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
   \centering
   \includegraphics[scale=.89,bb=0 0 291 279]{f1.png}
   \caption{Some description about the picture}
   \label{picture-label}
\end{figure}
TEXT \cite{1}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{References.bib}
\end{document}
```

But I did not get the `References` at the end of the PDF file, and also I did not get the citation after the text. instead I get `[?]`. How can I make my references show up in the text?

Comment: The following answer might be of help: [Unable to generate references using `.bib` in Texlipse](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/37731/5764). Even though it references Texlipse, it is probably independent and therefore should solve your problem. Please let us know.

Comment: How often did you compile your `LaTeX` file? Did you run BibTeX? It is not enough in this case to compile just once.

Comment: This may not be the reason but anyway, you should remove the extension from your reference file, i.e. `\biliography{References}`

Comment: The only citation you have seems to have a bibkey of 1. Is that really the bibkey?

Comment: to me the issue was I didn't actually use the citation I inserted, so it didn't put it in the bibliography in the pdf...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First of all, you have to remove the extension `.bib` from your `\bibliography` command; i.e. `\bibliography{References}` and make sure it is in the same folder as your compiles `.tex` file, if it is in a sub-directory then use `\bibliography{./References/References}` as an example.

You also have to make sure the entry is correct in your bibliography `.bib` file, I can see you use `cite{1}`, so I presume you have an entry in your `.bib` file as:

```
@book{1,
title={Book},
author={Author}
}
```

... of course you have to fill in all obligatory fields depending on entry type. [BibTeX Documentation](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/contrib/doc/).

For your compilation to work properly, you should compile in the following manner:

```
pdflatex file.tex && bibtex file.aux && pdflatex file.tex && pdflatex file.tex
```

This example being given for a `pdflatex` output, you could use `latex` ,`xetex` or whichever engine you use.

If you get a `[?]` in your citation instead of a proper reference number, check the log file for something like:

```
LaTeX Warning: Citation `1' on page 2 undefined on input line 51`
```

Comment: Thanks Ayman ,
It works now , but still not all citation appear properly.Some of them are still [?]

Comment: @Mohammed It's probably a typo in either the `\cite` command or the BibTeX entry; you could have a `@book{Mohammed,` entry and a `\cite{Mohammd}`, it's common. If the problem persists, provide an MWE for your `.tex` file and `.bib` file.

Comment: I am using TexMakerX , the problem is resolved now
I have to choose the citation EXPLICITLY form the pop-up menu after typing \cite

Comment: +1 for pointing that `bibtex file.aux` is not implicit in `pdflatex file.tex`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and just resolved it. Maybe you have the same mistake as mine.
My `.bib` file was named `ref.bib` and I was thinking: its name is `ref` and its postfix is `bib`. However, the `name.postfix` was `ref.bib.tex`. It was so because based on my PC settings, the postfix of files are not shown.  So I just changed it to `ref.bib` and resolved the problem.

You can check the postfix of your file in 'type' column of the folder your files are located if you change the view to "details".

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.